# Changing buttons background color while the button is being clicked

Tags: gwt, mobile, web-applications

While the button is pressed, I want the buttons background to be blue, and after the click event has occurred (and I have loaded/shown what needs to be done), I want the background color to go back to its default color.

If I do

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {   
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //Some code to change my background color of the button
            button.setBackgroundSearchAgainButton("0066CC");
        }
    });
```

This permanently changes my buttons background color to blue. How do then change it back to default since there is no OffClick event.
I was wondering if I could use onBlue event, but I dont know how to use it since it doesnt fall under `button.addClickHandler()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS styles. For example let's say, you have a style like:

```
.blue {
  background: #0066cc;
}
```

When the button is clicked you just add this style:

```
button.addStyleName("blue");
```

You can do this in the `ClickEvent` or the `MouseDownEvent`.

After you have done everything you wanted, you can just remove the style:

```
button.removeStyleName("blue");
```

And btw `onClick` doesn't mean that the click is now in ON state. This means this method will be called ON a click event, so it doesn't make sense to look for an `offClick` method.

Comment: I like your idea, however upon clicking my button; it turns dark blue (the standard blue which you see when you click a button) and also my light blue (the one i used using `button.addStyleName("blue"))`. How can I change the setting that my button goes dark blue upon clicking it

Comment: I think you are seeing the default GWT's styles. Try to delete/override them. Probably using !important in your custom styles should be enough.